# Пробелы в названии файла при удаленном копировании функцией copy

Tags: файлы, php

Всем привет.

Имеем файл

```
http://kannykkani.com/images/Sony Xperia S B.jpg
```

С таким названием скопировать не получается используя **copy**, так как в нем пробелы.
Недолго думая заменил через **str_replace** пробел на **%20** и проблема ушла.
Но вот ощущение того, что еще какая-то "ерись" может там попасться и картинка так же не загрузиться - осталась.

Может не стоит полагаться на **copy**, а юзать **curl**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy` и `curl` по функционалу разные функции. `Curl` скачивает файл, а `copy` копирует например когда закачиваешь файл из временной папки в указанную тобой. Не знаю как ты, но я бы просто использовал вместо пробела  нижний слеш чтобы не потерять файл.

Пример: `Sony_Xperia_S_B.jpg`

Сделать обработку `$_FILE['name']`

```
function replace_empty($string){
    $string = str_replace("_"," ",$string);
    return $string;
}
```

Поправьте, если не я не прав я как бы начинающий

Comment: copy работает с удаленными файлами. я качаю по ссылке, а не получаю из формы.

через str_replace я и так заменяю пробелы на %20, файл скачивается нормально. Но сомнения в том, что могут попадаться какие-то символы которые так же могут выдавать ошибку. У меня опыта в этом нет.

curl в данном случае работает корректно. просто хотел что по-проще использовать...

Comment: наверно если удаленный сервер лудше использовать Curl. Я уверен facebook и vk используют именно его. я для начала проверил бы существует файл на удаленном сервере

Comment: типа что-то этого:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php

Comment: Да, curl скорее всего и буду в итоге юзать. Просто не хотел накручивать, так как и copy вроде без особых проблем работает.

Answer (score 0):

[urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) вам в помощь

И да, для `copy()` можно задавать [контекст](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-context-create.php), при том так, что он еще и HTTP-авторизацию будет проходить при надобности, но лично мне `CURL` больше нравится. Я бы именно его и рекомендовал использовать.

Comment: Обработал urlencode, пишет Warning: copy(http%3A%2F%2Fkannykkani.com%2Fimages%2FSony%2520Xperia%2520S%2520B.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...


походу проще curl использовать. может есть какой-то класс-обертка для curl, чтобы удобно юзать все что нужно? Нашел функциональный zebra-curl, но не нравиться как работает используя функцию-калбек.